# Alterar informações da coluna do MySQL com UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Em resumo através do PHP abaixo consigo emitir as informações específicas já registradas na coluna no BD, só que, além de apenas "emitir" os dados de lá, eu gostaria de uma função que alterasse tais informações sem que a página fosse alterada. Eu tenho uma ideia de como fazer isso usando o código a seguir:

```
if ($action == 'okay') {
$conexao = mysql_query("update settingsMDP set name='$name', version='$version', startacp='$startacp' WHERE id='1'") or die ("Eita.. Deu errado!");
}
```

Se forem ver, se o `form action` é "okay" então, ele executa a UPDATE, mas... Isso não ocorre não sei por quê.

Este é o PHP.

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$server = "";
$usuario = "";
$banco   = "";
$senha = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$conexao = mysql_connect($server, $usuario, $senha);
$conexao = mysql_select_db("$banco",$conexao);
if(!$conexao) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$conexao = mysql_query("select * from settingsMDP");

//********************************************mudei aqui*****************************
$exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($conexao);

 if (empty($_REQUEST['action'])) $action = ''; else $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
 if ($action == 'okay') {
 $conexao = mysql_query("update settingsMDP set name='$name', version='$version', startacp='$startacp' WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Nome do MDP: </td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["name"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Versão: </td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["version"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Abertura do painel:</td>
            <td><input name="start_acp" type="text" id="startacp" value="<?php echo $exibe["startacp"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"> </td>
            <td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Salvar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Quando estiver desenvolvendo evite colocar erros personalizados, mude: `or die ("Eita.. Deu errado!");` para : `or die(mysql_error());`. De onde vem `$action`? no seu form existem 2 campos o mesmo nome(`name`) acredito que um deles deveria ser `version`.

Comment: Dê um var_dump($action) aí, acho que o problema está no $action.

Comment: var_dump? Acabei de editar o código. Seria isso que mencionou @Inkeliz? @rray eu já modifiquei o termo personalizado. Mas, por quê é aconselhável não usar?

Comment: Mais um adicional que não vai interferir muito no problema. Recomendo colocar chaves "{" por fora das variáveis na _string_, assim: `set name='{$name}',`. Para ajudar o PHP a identifica-las.

Comment: Seria para ver o que está no $action.

Comment: Com `mysql_error()` você recebe a mensagem de erro do banco, algo como `You have a syntax error at ......` que é bem melhor do que um `Deu erro!` que não te da nenhuma pista sobre o erro.

Comment: Funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5. Use PDO ou mysqli. Veja http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu vou mexer no que eu acho que é o que você quer. Vou aproveitar para resolver alguns outros problemas, mas não todos.

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$server = "";
$usuario = "";
$banco   = "";
$senha = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$conexao = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $senha);
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco);
if(!$conexao) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    exit;
}

if ($_POST["update"] == "Salvar") {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["name"]);
    $version = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["version"]);
    $startacp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["startacp"]);
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "update settingsMDP set name='$name', version='$version', startacp='$startacp' WHERE id='1'") or die (mysqli_error());
    echo "Gravou";
} else {
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from settingsMDP");
    $exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<form method="post">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Nome do MDP: </td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["name"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Versão: </td>
            <td><input name="version" type="text" id="version" value="<?php echo $exibe["version"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Abertura do painel:</td>
            <td><input name="startacp" type="text" id="startacp" value="<?php echo $exibe["startacp"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"> </td>
            <td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Salvar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/Update.php).

Não tenho como testar mas é algo assim.

Já que você está usando a mesma página para pegar os dados e atualizar você precisa decidir qual dos dois vai fazer. Isto pode ser feito se o botão de *submit* está presente ou não.

Fiz a chamada sanitização do conteúdo que veio para evitar [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101).

Mudei para o MySLQi que é uma função mais moderna e que é recomendada.

Consertei um erro de desatenção no nome dos campos do HTML.

Também havia uma confusão com a variável `$conexao` que causava a perda da referência para a conexão. Você não pode ficar reaproveitando a variável desse jeito.

Deixei a chama do `form` sem parâmetro que vai chamar o próprio URL dele.

E arrumei mais alguns detalhes. Eu ainda mudaria uma porção de coisas nesse código mas é melhor eu não mexer demais no que você está conseguindo fazer senão você vai se perder. Um código de qualidade para uso em produção teria que ser bem melhor que este. Embora já vi muito *site* rodando por aí com coisa até pior :P

Comment: A variável $conexão não é correspondente à conexão? Fiquei confuso agora neste ponto, pois, ela resgata a conexão com o BD, não é? A respeito da sua edição, agora me veio alguns erros: http://staff.zz.mu/mods/templates/siteconfig.php Essa versão moderna requer qual versão do PHP?

Comment: Sim, e você usa ele para várias coisa, não só para a conexão. `mysqli` está disponível desde a versão 4.1. Vou arrumar esses problemas, de fato esqueci de mudar os parâmetros que são mais organizados nele.

Comment: Dei uma melhorada no código, mas ele está tão cheio de erros que está difícil achar todos sem *debugar* todo ele. Tem erros de digitação/desatenção, confusões de uso de variáveis, lógica, etc.

Comment: Está mais do que perfeito amigo @bigown Obrigado por solucionar minhas dúvidas.

Comment: pelo que vi executando já melhorou, certo? Mas ainda tem outros problemas, vai perguntando aí coisas específicas.

Comment: Eu teria uma outra pergunta para mais tarde. Essa está resolvida. ;)