# Como acontece um SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

Por que criar parâmetros para cada campo que será atualizado ajuda a evitar SQL Injection? Exemplo:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone = @Telefone, " +
                             "Cidade = @Cidade, " +
                             "Email = @Email, " +
                             "Endereco = @Endereco " +
                             "WHERE Nome = @Nome", conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txtTelefone.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cidade", txtCidade.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endereco", txtEndereco.Text); 
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txtNome.Text);
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9734/como-evitar-sql-injection-em-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php
Esse post pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Como acontece um SQL Injection?

Vamos alterar seu exemplo um pouco:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone = " + txtTelefone.Text +  " " +
                         "WHERE Nome = @Nome", conn);
```

Suponha agora que eu digite em `txtTelefone` o seguinte comando:

```
0 where 1=0; drop database MeuSistema;
```

Dependendo da permissão do usuário, você concorda que o banco de dados inteiro pode ser apagado?

Isto é ***SQL Injection***. Normalmente ele não é usado para apagar bancos de dados, e sim para incluir informações falsas para sequestrar o sistema ou alterar seu comportamento.

Isto é bastante comum em *frameworks* fracos e de código aberto. Existem fontes de informação na Internet especializada em ataques a determinados *frameworks*. Em código fechado também pode acontecer.

> Por que criar parâmetros para cada campo que será atualizado ajuda a evitar SQL Injection?

Porque os parâmetros são avaliados antes de serem inseridos. Neste exemplo com `AddWithValue()` a checagem não é muito eficiente porque não há verificação do tipo de dados do parâmetro. [Aqui fala mais a respeito](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

Para estes casos, prefira o método [`Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ht4eset1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@Telefone", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Comment: Eu estava preparando uma bela resposta, mas você a fez primeiro. Claro que poderia existir um exemplo espetaculoso e mais claro, mas a resposta atende bem às "duas perguntas em uma".

Comment: "Isto é bastante comum em frameworks fracos e de código aberto": puxa, esta frase ficou bem forte Cigano :-) Principalmente quando quando você diz sobre código aberto. A impressão que passa é que este tipo de falha de segurança não acontece em código fechado. Se não acontecesse, então a própria Microsoft não teria o Patch Tuesday (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday).

Comment: Verdade cigano, você concordaria em retratar esse trecho?

Comment: @cantoni Um exemplo de *framework* fraco é o antigo PHPNuke (que originou o Joomla algum tempo depois). Na época, o conceito de SQL Sanitizing era algo novo. Vendi um site escrito nisso e tive que estudar bastante porque o site foi invadido alguns meses depois.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Colocaram letras na minha resposta, jovem. De qualquer forma, está complementado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, concordo que isso exista. Só não acho que que seja algo apenas do mundo do código aberto, como sua frase pode sugerir. Não existe garantia 100% de que um código fechado será mais bem escrito do que um código aberto e vice-versa. Minha visão é que, pelo menos no código aberto, você tem como ver como as coisas são feitas. Valeu pelo feedback. De qualquer maneira, a mudança fica a seu critério, mas acho que você poderia trocar o trecho "código aberto" pela experiência ruim que você teve com PHPNuke.

Comment: @cantoni Jovem, não sou responsável por aquilo que você entende. Apenas pelo que respondo, e eu não afirmei nada sobre código fechado até a minha edição. A resposta vai ficar desta forma mesmo, até porque o objetivo não é discutir código aberto vs. código fechado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, os comentários são pra gente discutir mesmo, certo? Se eu discordei é porque eu entendi de uma forma que talvez seja diferente da que você desejou passar.  Obviamente, você não é responsável por isso. Mas como você foi o autor da reposta e ela é pública acaba que você pode encontrar gente que pensa diferente. Totalmente natural desde que, obviamente, não ultrapasse os limites da educação e do bom senso.

Comment: @cantoni Sim, e agradeço pelo questionamento saudável. Acho pertinente seu ponto, e acrescento, não para os fins da resposta, mas como parte opinativa: o código aberto é excelente nessa função de *exploit* porque faz os desenvolvedores terem que desenvolver algo ótimo, justamente pra evitar ao máximo os *exploits*, dando maior robustez ao produto.

Answer (score 19):

Estes métodos sabem limpar o conteúdo, eles retiram qualquer texto potencialmente perigoso. Como ali se espera algo bem limitado, ou seja, apenas números ou um texto como *string* (entre aspas), qualquer coisa que fuja disto é considerado lixo e é descartado. Então elementos que façam parte da sintaxe do SQL não podem ser injetados na consulta alterando seu teor.

O problema da injeção ocorre por construção do texto da consulta de forma livre, aceitando qualquer coisa como algo válido. A proteção ocorre justamente por deixar que apenas algumas partes muito específicas sejam usadas de forma flexível e que venham de fonte externa.

O problema pode ocorrer em qualquer linguagem de programação normal e o erro é sempre do programador, seja porque ele não sabe como evitar o problema manualmente ou por não usar as ferramentas prontas que a biblioteca ou linguagem oferecem para inserir os dados parametrizados e só eles, sem deixar que outros dados entrem especialmente algum que pode ser confundido com um SQL válido que pode ser executado.

Aí vem o famoso XKCD

[image: XKCD SQL Injection]

É muito comum o programador concatenar *strings* para criar a consulta que será enviada para o banco de dados de forma ingênua, então ele faz algo assim:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE (nome = '" + GetByName + "' AND status = 'ativo')";
```

Sendo que esta variável `nome` é um texto que veio de uma fonte externa, por exemplo veio de um `POST` ou `GET` do HTTP em um site um aplicação web. Nada disso foi sanitizada e a concatenação ocorre assim. Algo assim é válido:

```
http://site.com/Student?GetByName=Joao
```

Assim também:

```
http://site.com/Student?GetByName=Robert');%20DROP%20TABLE%20STUDENTS;%20--
```

Aí o sujeito mal intencionado ou com um nome um pouco fora do comum pode causar danos no seu banco de dados. Supondo o exemplo do quadrinho essa *string* seria `Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --`, concatenado fica assim:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE (nome = 'Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; -- ' AND status = 'ativo')
```

Este é um comando perfeitamente válido que fará:

- selecionar todas as colunas da tabela `Students` aplicando um filtro onde a coluna `nome` tenha o texto `Robert`
- logo em seguida encerra este `SELECT` com o `;` e inicia outro comando onde a tabela `Students` é apagada completamente
- Finalmente ocorre um comentário que pode ter um texto qualquer que não dará erro, é tudo ignorado pelo banco de dados.

Se quiser uma leitura mais fácil:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE (nome = 'Robert');
DROP TABLE STUDENTS;
-- ' AND status = 'ativo')
```

Note que usei uma sintaxe agnóstica de linguagem na *string* lá em cima, quase todas teriam o comando assim (não há injeção de SQL sem um código em uma linguagem de programação em algum nível).

Obviamente que qualquer código SQL pode ser injetado e não só para apagar uma tabela que é uma molecagem de pouca utilidade. Existem milhões de sistemas por aí (principalmente web) que estão sendo usados indevidamente causando problemas e pequenos prejuízos sem a pessoa perceber por anos. Em geral quem faz isso toma o cuidado de não despertar muita atenção para fazer por muito tempo e obter maiores benefícios. Na soma os prejuízos são enormes. Há casos que você nem precisa mudar nada, só de ter acesso a uma informação sem o direito já pode causar muito estrago. Exemplo:

```
"SELECT * FROM Correntistas WHERE numConta = '" + numConta + "';"
```

Aí manda assim:

```
http://site.com/Correntistas?numConta=1%20OR%20TRUE
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Injection.sql).

O exemplo é ingênuo mas mostra que dá para fazer qualquer coisa, é só entender como é a *query* do outro lado e quase todas variam muito pouco, todo *<strike>hacker</strike>lamer* sabe fazer com o pé nas costas. É das coisas mais fáceis de violar que existe e das mais negligenciadas.

Como pode dar trabalho e você não observar todos detalhes que são necessários para garantir que não tenha a injeção é melhor usar uma função pronta da biblioteca da linguagem ou do componente de acesso ao banco de dados. Cada um terá seu jeito de fazer isto e o exemplo usado na pergunta é a forma correta de fazer em C#.

Outra fonte da piada do coitado do Bobby Tables é o [site dele](http://www.bobby-tables.com/) mostrando o problema e solução em várias linguagens.

Por causa disso já vi gente com nome `Null` ter problemas, nem era *injection* proposital.

Ele é mais comum do que parece. Ocorre mais entre amadores mas vira e mexe algum grande software feito por especialistas cai nessa. Note que hoje a solução é simples, a pessoa só precisa lembrar de usar. As que podem parecer mais elaboradas, as manuais tendem a fracassar, use o básico, o pronto, desde que possa confiar na ferramenta que usa (algumas bem conhecidas não são confiáveis). Então entenda tudo sobre o assunto pra ficar mais seguro.

Aqui tem mais sobre:

- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101)
- [Estou sofrendo ataques do tipo SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103512/101)
- [O que é o ponto de interrogação em uma query?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22621/101)
- [Expliquem de uma forma mais simples o que são esses ataques?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130149/101)

Answer (score 9):

> Como acontece um SQL Injection?

O usuário mal intencionado coloca códigos SQL no valor da variável e esses códigos são executados pelo banco.

### Exemplo:

Dado o código:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone = '" + telefone + "'" + 
                                 " WHERE Id = " + Id, conn);
```

Se o usuário colocar o valor 9999-9999 a query será:

```
UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone = '9999-9999' WHERE Id = 1
```

Legal, mas e se em vez do número de telefone ele colocasse essa linha abaixo?

```
' where 1=0; delete from Contatos; --
```

O resultado da query será:

```
UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone = '' where 1=0; delete from Contatos; --' WHERE Id = 1
```

Sendo assim, seria executado um update que não atualizaria nada, seguido de um delete inserido pelo usuário, e o comentário para ignorar o resto do comando.

> Por que criar parâmetros para cada campo que será atualizado ajuda a evitar SQL Injection?

Como respondido nessa pergunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection

> Porque quando você executa um SQLCommand usando SQLParameters, os parametros não são inseridos diretamente no comando. Ao invés disso, uma stored procedure nativa chamada sp_executesql é chamada e recebe a string do comando e um array de parâmetros.
> Com isso os parâmetros são isolados e tratados como dados ao invés de serem embutidos na query, consequentemente nenhum comando contido nos parâmetros podem ser "executados".