# Estou sofrendo ataques do tipo SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, segurança, sql-injection

Desde que abri um projeto online estou tendo problemas com invasão, onde alguém está fazendo inserções diretas no Banco de Dados. Foi o que me deu iniciativa para por em todas as variáveis recebidas através do método `$_GET` e `$_POST`. As funções:

```
$variavel = trim(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['recebe'])));
```

Utilizei dois programas para fazer *scanner* para analisar o site ('Acunetix' e 'Scrawlr'), onde na primeira vez retornou variáveis vulneráveis, mas agora fiz todo o procedimento nas mesma e agora não da mais sinal de problema.

Porém, mesmo assim, o atacante ainda consegue invadir o servidor, mesmo tendo a certeza depois de ter verificado todas as linhas de código do projeto..

Comment: Para começar eu diria para restaurares o backup mais recente, com certeza deves ter feito um mesmo antes do ataque. Verifica os ficheiros de log a ver se consegues encontrar as queries.

Comment: Uma pergunta simples: O seu servidor de banco de dados está exposto à internet ou ele só é acessível por meio do seu servidor web?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Esta no site, mas só é acessado pelos ADMs, mas sei que não esta sendo dessa forma pq, pelo painel no site, quando é inserido algum dados o script pega o id da conta, mas quando vejo que houve ataque e verifico no próprio servidor fica como '0', dizendo que não foi por conta

Comment: Tem certeza que não há nenhuma forma de se acessar o banco de dados diretamente sem ser por intermédio da aplicação? Porque se isso acontecer, basta ter o login e senha do banco de dados e já era. Aliás, você já trocou o login e a senha do banco de dados? Se ainda não trocou, recomendo que faça isso urgentemente.

Comment: Se seus site possui informações de usuários (email, login,senha etc) e  as senhas não estiverem devidamente criptografadas, emita um email alertando os usuários para modificarem senhas de seu email pessoal. Muitos usuários utilizam a mesma senha do email em outros serviços.

Comment: Não se esqueça de usar sempre prepared statments que evitam muito desses problemas.

Comment: Troque as senhas, principalmente do banco de dados, coloque um alias novo nas tabelas... mude o nome da base de dados, use placeholders nos métodos de insert / update, nunca passe parâmetros de inserção e atualização por GET, de preferência use um [csrf token](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) para POST por formulários, assim você validar o origem de publicação, para metodos restFul, use um token com autorização de tipo [Bearer Token](https://medium.com/tableless/entendendo-tokens-jwt-json-web-token-413c6d1397f6)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Depois de ter sido atacado ele pode ter colhido informações importantes que permitem que ele faça a invasão por outros meios. Quando você tem um servidor invadido não é simples torná-lo seguro novamente. Se não conseguiu fazer eficazmente o que é simples, que é deixá-lo seguro inicialmente, agora vai ser bem mais difícil. Ele pode até estar fazendo isto por ter acesso direto ao servidor agora.

Um especialista em segurança (raro encontrar um realmente capacitado) poderia fazer uma análise nesse servidor para ver se existe algo que possa ser feito. Se preferir por conta própria, o melhor caminho provavelmente é começar um servidor novo com todos dados diferentes, especialmente senhas. Não vá copiar nada que estava no servidor comprometido. Se tiver mesmo que copiar algo, terá que fazer análise minuciosa do conteúdo. E senhas, esqueça, isso não pode ser aproveitado.

A privacidade já era. Isso nunca mais terá solução, uma vez perdida, não volta mais.

Fora isso, o código provavelmente ainda está vulnerável. Esses softwares fazem análises superficiais, não confie neles como uma solução definitiva. Se não conseguir achar todas as vulnerabilidades terá que contratar um especialista. E cuidado, muita gente vende o que não tem.

Lembre-se que agora o atacante provavelmente conhece seu código e sabe explorar qualquer falha, até aquelas que antes passavam desapercebidas.

Veja mais em [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Um detalhe importante que eu não havia dito, mas como tem resposta sobre, PDO não é a solução para isto, pelo menos não mais que o uso nativo.

Answer (score 1):

Evite a utilização das funções mysqli_* e mysql_*, utilize PDO, trate as entradas dos dados.

Faz um `select` no seu banco e verifique os privilégios dos usuários, se há algum usuário "estranho", se *root* tem acesso externo sem senha, etc.

```
select user,password,host,grant_priv from mysql.user;
```

Executando a *query* acima, verifique se algum usuário (com o `host = %`, que seria acesso remoto)  está sem senha.
Não é garantido que ele tenha acesso ao banco de dados do modo que citei mas pode ocorrer. Verifique *logs* MySQL e PHP.

Como citou o @Maniero, o mais recomendável é contratar alguém que entenda sobre o assunto, raridade mas é possível.

Comment: `mysqli_*` também trata entrada de dados.

Answer (score 0):

**Solução que pode ajudar no seu problema:**

1. Troque todas as senhas de usuários, e principalmente a de acesso ao banco de dados, de preferência uma senha complexa, tipo: `#@_12!aVxzHors12_8^`.
2. Coloque um alias novo nas tabelas, exemplo, se a tabela for : `usuarios` => `t_db_usuarios` ...
3. Se possível, mude o nome da banco de dados, use "placeholders" com **Prepared Statements** nos métodos de insert / update:

**mysqli_***

```
$intVal = $_POST['id'];

$column1 = "exemplo 1";
$column2 = "exemplo 2";
$column3 = intval($intVal);


    $query = "INSERT INTO tabela_nome (column1_string, column2_string, column3_integer)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $column1, $column2, $column3);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
       echo "Sucesso!";
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

**PDO:**

```
try {

    //dados da conexao

    $intVal = $_POST['id'];
    $data = [
             ':column1_string' => 'exemplo1', 
             ':column2_string' => 'exemplo2',
             ':column3_integer' => intval($intVal),
    ];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela_nome (column1_string, column2_string, column3_integer)
    VALUES (:column1_string, :column2_string, :column3_int)";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $exec = $sth->execute($data);
    if ($exec) {
      echo "Sucesso!";
    }
   /*
    Se preferir não enviar como um array, também pode trabalhar cada dado inserido:

     $sth->bindParam(':column1_string', $data[':column1_string'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
     $sth->bindParam(':column2_string', $data[':column2_string'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
     $sth->bindParam(':column3_int', $data[':column3_int'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($sth->execute()) {
        echo "Sucesso";
    }
   */
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

4. **Nunca** passe parâmetros de inserção e atualização via GET. De
   preferência use um [csrf
   token](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)
   para formulários por método **POST**, assim você irá validar que a origem de
   publicação, corresponde do mesmo lugar de envio.

   Para APIs RestFul, use um token com autorização de tipo [Bearer
   Token](https://medium.com/tableless/entendendo-tokens-jwt-json-web-token-413c6d1397f6), projeta origem de CORS para o seu domínio do site, proteja-se de [ataques por
   XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

   ```
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.seudominio.com.br');
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
   ```
5. Utilize alguma ferramenta de verificação de vulnerabilidade de sites, aqui algums exemplos:

   > https://www.scanmyserver.com/
   >   https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html
   >   https://detectify.com/
   >   https://www.newnettechnologies.com/vulnerability-tracker.html