# Salvando campos com vírgula

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados

O que eu preciso fazer para salvar em um campo valores do tipo moeda com a vírgula e mandar para o com a vírgula.

Como declarei o campo preço no banco:

```
preco number(12,2),
```

Código:

```
class clnPrato {

 private string _preco;

 public string preco {
  get {
   return _preco;
  }
  set {
   _preco = value;
  }

 }

 public void Gravar() {
  string strQuery;
  strQuery = "INSERT INTO Prato";
  strQuery += (" VALUES(");
  strQuery += ("'" + _preco + "',");
  strQuery += (")");
  clnBancoDados ObjClnBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
  ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
 }
```

Botão Salvar:

```
private void btnsalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 clnPrato Prato = new clnPrato();

 Prato.preco = maskpreco.Text;

 if (ObjOperacao == clnFuncoesGerais.Operacao.Inclusao) {
  Prato.Gravar();
 }
}
```

Comment: Enzo se.vc configurou o banco corretamente, e errou no seu design da classe que deveria ter o tipo decimal, porque tem esse proposito errado de gravar com virgula? por exemplo consultas nesse campo pra darem certo se forem gravado com virgula vai precisar de conversão sendo mais custoso diminuindo o desempenho. No seu código você tem um problema deveria usar `paramenters` e não SQL pura.

Comment: Eu uso no asp.net mvc c# <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"> no Web.config para gravar no ms sql server do tipo decimal(99,99) com virgula, exemplo: PrecoVenda (decimal(10,2), not null). Ressalto que isso é para gravar se for para editar e mostrar na tela ai tem outras ações com relação a plugins de validação.

Comment: Na verdade eu quero trazer os preços salvos para fazer cálculo, esse é o motivo de querer salvar com vírgula. Coloquei o campo como string, apenas para fazer testes, sabia que estava errado. Usei SQL porque foi assim que eu aprendi, já me falaram que estava errado e já me falaram para usar paramenters, não usei porque ainda não sei "o que é" e também não sei como usar. Estou dando uma estudada.

Comment: @enzo Não faça testes do jeito errado. Isso não ajuda você aprender, nem as pessoas responderem adequadamente. Quando alguém diz que está fazendo errado, mude o jeito de fazer. Se não sabe como usar, consulte o manual, procure um livro que ensine de forma estruturada como fazer certo e até pergunte especificamente sobre isso, mas não faça errado. Vou melhor um pouco a resposta.

Comment: @enzo A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Há um problema de tipo, não use uma propriedade de texto para guardar um valor monetário. Mudando isso já deve ajudar.

Esse código não faz muito sentido, é complicado inserir algo que seja só o preço, mas tudo bem. Não sei bem a estrutura usada, vou postar como eu faria (do jeito certo, evitando vazamento de memória):

```
using var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
using var command = new OracleCommand("insert into prato (preco) values (:Preco)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Preco", Preco);
command.Connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Oracle.cs).

Até dá para abstrair a conexão, mas precisa garantir sua finalização e a parametrização para [evitar injeção de SQL e não sofrer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103512/101).

## Propriedade

Também é muito mais simples declarar um propriedade assim:

```
public decimal Preco { get; set; }
```

## `MaskedTextBox`

Se ainda quiser usar o `MaskedTextBox` na apresentação terá que converter o valor. Quando ler o dado do banco de dados terá que converter para *string*, provavelmente com `ToString()` dando o [formato que desejar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Para converter o valor lido no interface com o usuário para o valor decimal precisa tentar fazer um *parse*. Já [respondi isso antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56288/101).

Entenda a diferença entre dado a apresentação do dado. A apresentação você pode fazer do jeito que desejar, o dado não tem nada de vírgula ou não, é um número com parte inteira e parte decimal. O dado existe sem formato.

## Cultura

Se deseja controlar ou converter o formato pode estar sobre o [sistema de cultura do .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

As funções de conversão de tipos, especialmente entre `string` e tipos numéricos permitem escolher qual cultura deseja usar.

É possível também determinar a cultura específica da aplicação (na verdade da *thread*) para uso geral e para a interface com usuário, e não ficar dependendo da configuração do sistema operacional. Por exemplo:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Na verdade fazer certo exige um conhecimento mais profundo. Já adianto que desenvolver software não é tão simples quanto parece. Tem muito detalhe que precisa ser observado e várias combinações possíveis, algumas que funcionam bem, outra que não dão certo.

Comment: Sabia que estava errado, deixei assim porque estava do jeito que eu queria. Quando eu mudo para decimal, o valor que ele grava é 0, mesmo eu colocando outro. Estou inserindo outros valores também, deixei só o preco para simplificar. Tirei a MaskedTextBox e coloquei um TextBox, ainda tenho que converter?

Comment: Sim, note que o nome deles contém um `Text`, ou seja, não é valor, então precisa converter. Claro que dá para criar abstrações para ajudar fazer isso de forma transparente, mas isso é bem mais avançado.

Comment: Se eu fosse usar esse seu exemplo, ele ficaria dentro do botão salvar? Esse código do Thread que você deu de exemplo, eu também deveria usar? E se eu fosse usar o seu exemplo, eu deveria apagar o meu método Gravar?

Comment: @enzo não, tanto que ele ignorei esse método. Não sei se deveria usar a cultura diretamente. Vai depender da implementação, do contexto. Novamente, precisa entender o todo para saber quando usar cada coisa. Eu não posso olhar para um trecho, que na verdade nem funciona e dizer para você se deve ou não usar algo que vai mudar toda a aplicação. Te dei uma opção, só você sabe se ela é boa para seu caso. Por isso deve entender o funcionamento completo de cultura. Programação não é seguir uma receita única.

Comment: Ok. Muito Obrigado. E valeu pela paciência.