# Como utilizar vários "if"s exclusivos em PHP?

Tags: php, algoritmo

Eu quero fazer uma condição para quando um valor é selecionado, a condição está assim no momento:

```
if (!empty($_GET['faixa_de_preco'])) {

    $valor = $_GET['faixa_de_preco'];

    if ($valor == 1) {
        $result = "< 1000000.00";
    }
    if ($valor == 2) {
        $result = ">= 1000000.00 AND price <= 2000000.00";
    }
    if ($valor == 3) {
        $result = ">= 2000000.00 AND price <= 3000000.00";
    }else{
        $result = "";
    }

    $filter .= " AND price {$result}";

}
```

O que acontece é o seguinte, sempre que eu adiciono mais um `if` ele ignora o de cima. Um exemplo, nesse código, quando eu seleciono um option com o valor 3, funciona ou seja o único `if` que funciona é o

```
if ($valor == 3) {
        $result = ">= 2000000.00 AND price <= 3000000.00";
    }
```

quando eu seleciono um option com o valor 1 ou 2, ele cai no `else`, e caso eu adicione mais um `if`, o `if ($valor == 3)` começa a cair no `else` também.

Comment: O problema é sua lógica. Veja que quando $valor == 1 (ou 2) da maneira como fez ele entrará no `if ($valor == 3) {` e como será obrigatoriamente diferente executará o `else`. Utilize `else` em todos os `if`. Note também que quando $valor for diferente de 1, 2 e 3 seu filtro ficará errado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem 3 `if`s independentes e não um `if` só, que é o que parece desejar, e como todos eles mudam o valor da mesma variável só o último prevalecerá, seja verdadeiro ou falso.

Se realmente quer que só uma dessas opções executem elas devem ser um bloco só, assim todas passam ser mutualmente excludentes, no momento só a última é assim. Para fazer isso preciz ter um `else` em todos eles. Assim:

```
if (!empty($_GET['faixa_de_preco'])) {

    $valor = $_GET['faixa_de_preco'];

    if ($valor == 1) {
        $result = "< 1000000.00";
    } else if ($valor == 2) {
        $result = ">= 1000000.00 AND price <= 2000000.00";
    } else if ($valor == 3) {
        $result = ">= 2000000.00 AND price <= 3000000.00";
    } else {
        $result = "";
    }
    $filter .= " AND price {$result}";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Ifs.php).

Muito provavelmente usará isso em uma *query* SQL e pode estar cometendo um grave erro de [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103512/101). E parece que tem outros problemas, mas não dá para saber só com o que vimos. Leia também: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101)

Dependendo do caso pode ser que um `switch` resolva também, mas não vamos adicionar complexidade antes de entender o básico.

Comment: Entendi, era exatamente isso muito obrigado. Pode deixar que vou ler sobre SQL Injection e a validação via cliente para não cometer esse erro.

Comment: Onde está o erro de SQL Injection? Nesse caso há total controle sobre a variável `$result`, não tem como ser injetado um SQL através do `$_GET['faixa_de_preco']`. Ao meu ver fazer dessa forma é melhor do que por bind

Comment: Eu não disse que tem, mas que pode ter, depende do que mais for fazer.

Comment: Considerando que tem um AND na concatenação, tem uma probabilidade significativa de ter outro critério não necessariamente tratado contra injeção antes desse trecho.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser, alternativatimente, resolvido com um Switch visto que tem apenas uma condição no if

```
  if (!empty($_GET['faixa_de_preco'])) {
    $valor = $_GET['faixa_de_preco'];
    switch ($valor) {
        case 1:
            $result = "< 1000000.00";
            break;
        case 2:
            $result = ">= 1000000.00 AND price <= 2000000.00";
            break;
        case 3:
            $result = ">= 2000000.00 AND price <= 3000000.00";
            break;
        default:
            $result = "";
    }
    $filter .= " AND price {$result}";
}
```