# Ligação n para n

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Tenho uma base de dados e queria fazer ligação n para n no *C#*, mas não sei com faço para ir buscar os dados da minha outra tabela.

Eu queria que onde diz `id_equipa` aparece-se os dados da equipa que for selecionada na `combobox`

Passo a demonstrar o código :

```
public Jogadores()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dataTable = Database.DatabaseAPI.SelectDataTable(@"Select Jogador.Id_Jogador, Jogador.Nome_Jogador, Jogador.Idade, Jogador.País, Jogador.id_equipa from Jogador Join Equipa on Jogador.id_equipa = Equipa.Nome");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Id_Jogador"].Visible = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Database.DatabaseAPI.NonQuery("INSERT INTO Jogador(Id_Jogador, Nome_Jogador, Idade, País, Jogador.id_equipa) Values (NewID(), '" + textBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + textBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + comboBox1.ValueMember.ToString() + "')");
                if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nome em Falta");
                    return;
                }
                if (textBox2.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Idade em Falta");
                    return;
                }
                if (textBox3.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("País em Falta");
                    return;
                }
                if (comboBox1.Text.Trim() == "Escolha uma :")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Equipa em Falata");
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Dados do Jogador adicionado com sucesso!");
                DataTable dataTable = Database.DatabaseAPI.SelectDataTable(@"Select Id_Jogador, Nome_Jogador, Idade, País from Jogador Join Equipa on Jogador.id_equipa = Equipa.id_equipa");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
```

Exemplo da tabela :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da *combobox*  :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        private void Jogadores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = @"server =PC-SQLEXPRESS;database = Tabelaas;UID=sa;password=1234";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select id_equipa, Nome From Equipa", con))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row[1] = "Escolha uma :";
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

                    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome";
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id_equipa";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Como acontece um SQL injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection)

Comment: Como é que está a preencher a `ComboBox`? Edite a sua questão e coloque lá o código.

Comment: @JoãoMartins desculpe a demora estava sem computador, mas já está ai tudo.

Comment: Altere `comboBox1.ValueMember.ToString()` para `comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()`.

Comment: Para evitar o *SQL Injection* deve utilizar, por exemplo, `SqlParameters` ao invés de concatenar `strings`.