# Evitar SQL Injection - com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Quando tento logar na página de administração do site com **' OR 1=1 --** no login e senha ele permite o acesso!

Estou tentando utilizar a função seguinte, mas continuo com acesso sem permissão:

```
function protect( &$str ) {
        if( !is_array( $str ) ) {                      
                $str = preg_replace( '/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop|union|order|update|database)/i', '', $str );
                $str = preg_replace( '/(&lt;|<)?script(\/?(&gt;|>(.*))?)/i', '', $str );
                $tbl = get_html_translation_table( HTML_ENTITIES );
                $tbl = array_flip( $tbl );
                $str = addslashes( $str );
                $str = strip_tags( $str );
                return strtr( $str, $tbl );
        } else {
                return array_filter( $str, "protect" );
        } }
```

Na tela que verifica o login, tem o seguinte código:

```
session_start();
$login = protect($_SESSION['login']));
$senha = protect($_SESSION['senha']));
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda? Como bloqueio esse tipo de acesso?

Comment: Sugestão, delete essa função maluca aí o quanto antes. Volta e meia aparece uma dessas aqui no site, a maior parte foi tirada de um blog em que o próprio autor dizia não saber o que estava fazendo (e foi detonado nos comentários merecidamente). Além de não servir para nada útil, ela gera um monte de efeitos colaterais indesejáveis. A desgraça original chamava [`anti_injection`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=anti_injection), se não me engano. Quando tiver 10.000 pontos de reputação poderá ver algumas versões que já foram deletadas aqui do site.

Comment: Obrigado, Bacco! Irei ver o post que foi marcado!!!

Comment: Eu peguei os principais que eu lembrei como referência, mas dê uma pesquisada nos links relacionados que aparecem ao lado de cada post. O importante é aprender a escapar as strings com funções nativas e tratar sempre os dados que vem do lado do cliente. Tem vários posts no site tratando de injeção e também de segurança de senhas.

Comment: Esse é legal pra vc entender como acontece: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection?r=SearchResults&s=1|92.4600