# Como utilizar parâmetros na consulta sql utilizando dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

Como posso fazer um select simples utilizando o Dapper e passando mais de um parâmetro?

**Método:**

```
public IEnumerable<Locais> ConsultarPorTermo(string termo)
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Locais " +
     "WHERE Nome LIKE '%@term%' or Cidade LIKE '%@term%' or Estado LIKE '%@term%';";

    //utilizando a connection do EF
    return Db.Database.Connection.Query<Locais>(sql, new { term = termo });
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Não apresenta erro de sintaxe mas o seguinte erro:

> error CS0103: O nome "$exception" não existe no contexto atual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não estou certo sobre o erro que você está recebendo. Não tem como identificar este problema com as informações que você passou na pergunta, provavelmente nem tem a ver com essa consulta.

De qualquer forma, é fato que está passando errado o parâmetro para o Dapper.

É necessário concatenar o caracter `%` na string de consulta, da forma como está fazendo o Dapper não vai fazer a substituição do parâmetro, pois entende que se trata de um literal.

Uma alternativa é fazer assim:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Locais> ConsultarPorTermo(string termo)
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Locais " +
     "WHERE Nome LIKE @term or Cidade LIKE @term or Estado LIKE @term;";

    return Db.Database.Connection.Query<Locais>(sql, new { term = $"%{termo}%" });
}
```

É importante ressaltar a importância de **não fazer isto** direto na string que forma a *query*. A forma mostrada abaixo pode deixar sua aplicação vulnerável à injeção de SQL.

```cs
sql = "... WHERE Nome LIKE '%{termo}%' ...";
```

Você pode ver mais sobre em [**Como acontece um SQL Injection?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/18246)

Comment: obrigado! queria uma alternativa para não passar a string diretamente na query, mas consegui resolver tambem concatenando os sinais antes de mandar pro dapper

Comment: Só faltou falar pra ele nunca concatenar string, você vê que não sendo explícito nisso a pessoa ainda insiste em fazer errado. (estou sem votos pra hoje)

Comment: @Maniero Bem notado. Adicionei uma nota referente a isto.