# Como mostrar apenas os registos exactamente iguais aos que foram digitados?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho este código que mostra todos os registos desde que o numero ou letra inicial sejam iguais, mas eu queria mostrar apenas o registos que são exatamente iguais aos que foram digitados no campo de pesquisa, ou então mostrar no máximo 5 registos.

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';

$letter = $_GET["letter"];


$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 AND palavra LIKE '".$letter."%'" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 ORDER BY abc" ;

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pegando como exemplo uma de suas consultas:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 AND palavra LIKE '".$letter."%'" ;
```

Colocando limite de 5 resultados, usando o **limit**:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 AND palavra LIKE '".$letter."%' limit 5" ;
```

Ou exatamente igual ao termo digitado:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 AND palavra = '".$letter."'" ;
```

Caso não conheça, aconselho a dar uma olhada em [sql injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection/100731).

Comment: Ok Benilson, optei pela função limit 5, mas os dados aparecem de forma descendente (artigo 107, artigo 11, artigo 1), quando devia ser  artigo 1,  artigo 11, artigo 107... etc.

Comment: Usa order by em conjunto com limit, "order by campo_desejado asc limit 5"

Comment: Ok já está corrigido, eu lhe agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

O código correcto para responder à pergunta é o seguinte, limitando o número de registos mostrados e ordenando-os por um dos campos da tabela:

$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 AND palavra LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY id asc limit 5" ;

Comment: Para melhorar esta pergunta, como mostrar apenas os registos com uma letra maiúscula associada ao registo principal? O código acima mostra os registos que incluam o nº inicial que foi digitado até ao limite de 5 (1, 11, 19, 107, 115...). Sendo que o campo a pesquisar tem artigos numerados com a palavra "Artigo" como padrão (Artigo 107.º -, Artigo 107.º-A - ...), como mostrar só os registos com o número digitado, por exemplo 107, e os que tenham uma letra maiúscula e mantendo o limite de 5 (exemplo: Artigo 107.º -, Artigo 107.º-A -, Artigo 107.º-B -, Artigo 107.º-C -, Artigo 107.º- D)?