# Erro de headers em api com nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-headers

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
rodando na porta 3000, Ctrl+C para parar
/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/routes/user/login.js:24:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/jeffersonrodrigues/Dev/nodeProjects/minhaescola_api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Eis o meu código da API:

```
require('dotenv-safe').config();

const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const db = require('../../model/bd');

//config express
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var matricula = req.body.matricula;
    var senha = req.body.senha;

    db.query(`select * from aluno where mat_aluno='${matricula}' and senha='${senha}' `, (error, results) => {
        if (error || results.lenght === 0) {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Falha na autenticacao',
            });
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({ 
            id_aluno : results[0].mat_aluno 
        },
        process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.setHeader({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        res.status(200)
            .json({
                message: 'Autenticado',
                token,    
                data: results
            }
        );
        return;
    });
    res.status(404).json({
       message: 'Usuario nao encontrado',
    });
    return;
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está sempre executando o seguinte código:

```js
res.status(404).json({
  message: 'Usuario nao encontrado'
});
```

Ele define o *status* da resposta como 404 e uma resposta em JSON, que também acaba definindo o *header* de resposta `Content-Type` como `application/json`. Após isso, o *callback* da *query* ao banco de dados está sendo executado, o que estará novamente enviando uma resposta ao cliente:

```js
res.status(401).json({
  message: 'Falha na autenticacao'
});

// OU:

res.status(200).json({
  message: 'Autenticado',
  token,    
  data: results
});
```

Isso causa erros, já que não é permitido enviar outros cabeçalhos após o corpo da resposta ter sido iniciado. Da forma como o seu código foi estruturado, o seguinte está acontecendo:

1. Enviar *status* 404, cabeçalho `Content-Type` e **iniciar o corpo** da resposta.
2. Enviar *status* 401 ou 200, cabeçalho `Content-Type` e mais alguma parte do corpo. **Isso é incorreto.** Como disse acima, não se envia cabeçalhos após o corpo ter sido iniciado.

---

É importante ter em mente a natureza **assíncrona** do JavaScript. O seu código evidentemente não leva isso em conta.

Para arrumá-lo, você deve colocar **todas** as respostas **dentro** do *callback*, ou reestruturar o seu código. Nesse último caso, `async`/`await` pode vir a ser uma opção.

Mantendo os *callbacks*, você pode fazer isto:

```js
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const matricula = req.body.matricula;
  const senha = req.body.senha;

  // prettier-ignore
  db.query(`select * from aluno where mat_aluno='${matricula}' and senha='${senha}' `, (error, results) => {
    if (error || results.lenght === 0) {
      res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Falha na autenticacao'
      });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id_aluno: results[0].mat_aluno },
      process.env.SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '1h' }
    );

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Autenticado',
      token,
      data: results
    });
  });
});
```

Note que agora todos as respostas ao cliente estão dentro do *callback*, o que irá garantir que a resposta só seja enviada **após** o resultado (ou erro) da consulta.

Eu também removi esta linha de código:

```js
res.setHeader({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

É desnecessária, já que [`res.json`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) já define esse cabeçalho para você.

---

Como última nota, é importante dizer que a sua *query* está extremamente suscetível à uma grave vulnerabilidade, a [Injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). Para saber mais, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection).