# Converter retorno de query para Integer

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, cast

Como posso fazer o Cast de uma query para Integer?
Segue o que tentei executar.

```
public Integer validaPrincipal(String usuario, Integer tipo) {

    try{
         return (Integer) session.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery("select count(*) from tb_sega_vip_sec where ID_VIP = '"+usuario+"' and TIPO = '"+tipo+"'").getSingleResult();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

e o erro apresentado:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Não tem com fazer cast de `BigDecimal` para `Integer`, você precisa converte-lo para int primeiro com o método apropriado, no caso `intValue()`.

Comment: Então no caso vou ter que pegar o retorno da minha query e tratar ele com o intValue()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem de erro diz tudo: foi retornado um [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), que é incompatível com [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), por isso não é possível fazer o *cast* de um para outro (só seria possível se um fosse subclasse do outro).

A solução é primeiro pegar o `BigDecimal` e depois usar o método [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue--), que retorna um inteiro. Lembrando que `intValue()` retorna um `int`, então será feito um [*autoboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) para `Integer`.

Outro detalhe é que ao concatenar os valores do id e do tipo direto na query, sua aplicação fica vulnerável a [SQL injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/112052). Prefira usar `setParameter` que evita este tipo de problema:

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession()
    .createNativeQuery("select count(*) from tb_sega_vip_sec where ID_VIP = :id and TIPO = :tipo");
query.setParameter("id", usuario);
query.setParameter("tipo", tipo);
return ((BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo Adendo. irei testar a solução e alterar o tipo de concatenação.