# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, java-ee

Meu código de pesquisar no BD pelo `id`. A classe é `ContatoDao`:

```
    //Pesquisa por id
public Contato pesquisaId(int id) {
    
    
    String sql = "select nome from contatos where id = "+id;
    Contato contato = null;
    
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        
        if(rs.next()) {
            contato = new Contato();
            contato.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            contato.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            contato.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            contato.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        //return contato;
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //throw new DAOException("Erro ao pesquisar no banco de dados pelo id.");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return contato;
    
}
```

Esse outro é o código da classe de teste desse código acima:

```
    package br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste;

import br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao;
import br.com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato;

public class TestaPesquisaId {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();
        Contato contato = dao.pesquisaId(1);
        
        System.out.println("Nome: "+contato.getNome());
        
    }

}
```

Este é o erro que mostra no console:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao.pesquisaId(ContatoDao.java:101)
    at br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste.TestaPesquisaId.main(TestaPesquisaId.java:11)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:556)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:829)
    at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao.pesquisaId(ContatoDao.java:90)
    ... 1 more
```

Um detalhe: Esse `id` existe sim no banco, inseri com o método `inserirContato` que eu criei.

Comment: Não concatene o ID na query, isso deixa a aplicação vulnerável a ataques de [SQL injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/112052). Prefira usar os *setters* do `PreparedStatement`, exemplos: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection#1parameterized-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O texto da sua `query` não possui a coluna `id`, apenas a `nome`. Todos os campos que você pretende obter devem estar no `SELECT`:

```
...
String sql = "select id, nome from contatos where id = " + id;
...
```

Um outro ponto é o que o [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) comentou. Utilize o campo como parâmetro ao invés de concatenar na `query`:

```
...
stmt.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, nome from contatos where id = ?");
...
```

Comment: Obrigado! Foi falta de atenção, porque eu to pegando todas as colunas no rs.

Comment: Na verdade o `setInt` e demais parâmetros são feitos no `PreparedStatement`, não no `ResultSet`