# Como inserir um "if" em uma string de INSERT no banco?

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho a seguinte variável

```
 DateTime ContaRecebeDataPagto = Convert.ToDateTime(dgOrigem.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

Ela recebe um valor da `DataGrid`, em alguns casos a data do pagamento, e em outros casos não tem nada, pois não tem pagamento.

E tenho o seguinte `INSERT` que faço com o resultado do `DataGridView`:

```
//INSERT TABELA DESTINO
                string sqlIncluir = "INSERT INTO CONTARECEBER (" +
                    "CLIENTE," +
                    "VENCIMENTO," +
                    "DATAPAGAMENTO," + .........
                    ") Values(" +
                    "\'" + "," + "\'" + ContaReceCliente +         //CLIENTE
                    "\'" + "," + "\'" + ContaReceVencimento +//  + //VENCIMENTO
                    "\'" + "," + "\'" + ContaRecebeDataPagto.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")+ ........  +//DATAPAGTO
```

Na linha onde tem `ContaRecebeDataPagto`, teria que ter um `if` tipo `se != de vazio puxar, senão colocar null`, e ir continuando com as demais informações.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas: não concatene as variáveis diretamente na query, pois isso deixa o código vulnerável a ataques de SQL injection. Saiba mais lendo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/112052

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um [operador ternário](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) para não ter que criar mais linhas

```
 DateTime ContaRecebeDataPagto = dgOrigem.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value == null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(dgOrigem.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
```

Como ler uma operação ternária:

`ContaRecebeDataPagto == null` teste para ver se a variável é nula

`? null` o valor depois da interrogação será o valor retornado se a condição for verdadeira

`: Convert.ToDateTime(dgOrigem.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString())` o valor depois dos dois pontos é o que será retornado caso a condição for falsa

Basicamente é um if de uma linha só, ou seja:

```
ContaRecebeDataPagto == null ? null : ContaRecebeDataPagto.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

É a mesma coisa que fazer o seguinte (Que também é uma alternativa):

```
if(dgOrigem.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value == null)
    ContaRecebeDataPagto = null
else
    ContaRecebeDataPagto = Convert.ToDateTime(dgOrigem.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
```

Se o que você quer fazer é fazer esse teste na string, é muito simples também, só adicionar o operador na linha que você precisa do teste:

```
"\'" + "," + "\'" + ContaRecebeDataPagto == null ? "" : ContaRecebeDataPagto.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")+ ........  +//DATAPAGTO
```

Seguindo a mesma lógica, se a variável `ContaRecebeDataPagto` for nula, será inserido uma string vazia (`""`). Se não, será inserido a data normalmente.

Comment: obrigado vitor, valeu vou testar aqui e te aviso