# Rodar teste unitário com banco em memória e fromsqlraw está dando erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testes-de-unidade

Estou tentando construir um teste unitário com .Net Core 3.1 e usando o XUnit. Acontece que eu ainda não tenho banco de dados e por isso eu uso o `UseInMemoryDatabase`. Acontece que quando eu faço a chamada da PROC, eu pego esse erro:

> Unhandled method: FromSqlOnQueryable

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para testar a proc com banco inmemory. Não consegui substituir o `FromSqlRaw` por algo que funcione. Veja só meu código como está:

```
public IDeadlineCardGateway CreateRepository()
{
    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<DeadlineCardRepository>>();
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
    
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>()
       .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "LogisticaDB")
       .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

    _dBContext = new DBContext(builder.Options);

    return new DeadlineCardRepository(logger, null, _dBContext);
}
```

e aqui vai o método de teste

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "GetDeadlineCard: Calculation of working days")]
public async void GetDeadlineCard_ValidCEP()
{
    const string CEP_INICIAL = "23000980";
    const string CEP_FINAL = "99999999";
    const int COD_PROD = 9;
    var repository = CreateRepository();
    var expectedResult = new DeadlineCard(
        "Teste", 
        CEP_INICIAL, 
        CEP_FINAL, 
        COD_PROD
    );

    _dBContext
        .Set<DeadlineCard>()
        .FromSqlRaw($"[dbo].[SPEG8160_CALCULAR_PRAZO_ENTREGA] {CEP_INICIAL}, {COD_PROD}", 
        expectedResult);

    var result = await repository
        .GetDeadlineCard(CEP_INICIAL, COD_PROD.ToString());
        
    Assert.Equal(expectedResult.Prazo, result.Prazo);
}
```

O erro acontece nessa linha:

```
var result = await repository.GetDeadlineCard(CEP_INICIAL, COD_PROD.ToString());
```

Alguém sabe como eu resolvo isso?

Vi que o erro está acontecendo na classe a ser testada e não na classe de testes. Abaixo a classe:

```
public class DeadlineCardRepository : RepositoryBase<DeadlineCard, int>, IDeadlineCardGateway    
{
    private readonly ILogger<DeadlineCardRepository> log;
    private readonly DBContext dBContext;

    public DeadlineCardRepository(ILogger<DeadlineCardRepository> log, IMapper mapper, DBContext dBContext) : base(log, dBContext)
    {
        this.dBContext = dBContext;
        this.log = log;
    }
    public async Task<DeadlineCard> GetDeadlineCard(string cep_inicial, string codigo_produto)
    {
        //log.LogDebug("Method DBRepository GetDeadlineCard called");
                
        var prazo = await dBContext.Set<DeadlineCard>().FromSqlRaw("SPEG8160_CALCULAR_PRAZO_ENTREGA {0}, {1}", cep_inicial, codigo_produto)
            .ToListAsync();
        
        if (prazo == null)
            return null;

        return  prazo.FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O mesmo problema contido na pergunta do SO<sup>En</sup> [Entity Framework Core FromSqlRaw mock test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371446/entity-framework-core-fromsqlraw-mock-test-cases), relata mediante o [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19005) que o banco em memória não suporta execução de SQL puras e a solução seria utilizar um banco de dados local para testes.

Em outro pergunta do SO<sup>En</sup> [Raw sql with EF Core and in-memory db provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082301/raw-sql-with-ef-core-and-in-memory-db-provider) diz: [o banco de dados em memória é um banco NoSQL não relacional e por isso não aceita execução SQL puras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082502/6797930).

Enfim o seus testes devem ser feitos em um banco local que aceite SQL puras para testes unitários, além disso quando for construir esse tipo de abordagem utilize sempre o `SqlParameter` como exemplo logo abaixo:

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_PEOPLES_CREATE 
    @Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Peoples (Name) VALUES (@Name);
    SELECT * FROM Peoples WHERE Id = (SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT));
END
GO
```

**Código:**

*Classe:*

```
public class People
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Método com* `Stored Procedure`*:*

```
public People SPPeopleCreate(People p)
{
    var name = new SqlParameter("Name", p.Name); 
    var result = Set<People>().FromSqlRaw("SP_PEOPLES_CREATE @Name", name).ToList();
    if (result != null && result.Count == 1) return result[0];
    return null;
}
```

ou seja, nunca passe diretamente na sua SQL pode ter problemas de [Injeção de SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection).

[Talvez uma solução que possa seguir é utiliza SQLite em memória](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite), exemplo da configuração:

```
public class SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest : 
    ItemsControllerTest, IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;

    public SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest()
        : base(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ItemsContext>()
                .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                .Options)
    {
        _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(ContextOptions).Connection;
    }

    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");

        connection.Open();
        
        return connection;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();
}
```

<sup>***Fonte:*** [Using SQLite to test an EF Core application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite)</sup>

Comment: novic, obrigado pela ajuda. Vou levar em consideração sua solução sim. Esse é meu primeiro teste usando .net core e in-memory.

Comment: @pnet fiz um alteração onde você pode testar em outro provedor dê uma olhada! e se for útil aceite como resposta