# Qual a diferença de usar $_POST['campo'] e filter_input(INPUNT_POST,'campo')?

Tags: php, php-7

```
// Método 1
$campo = $_POST['campo'];

// Método 2
$campo2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'campo');
```

Qual a melhor forma de pegar dados no formulário?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Essencialmente nada diferente. Se usar alguma especificação de filtro na função, aí pode ser diferente, porque um filtro será usado e algum dado será limpo dentro de especificação usada. Isso pode ser visto com mais detalhes na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

De acordo com a documentação, da forma que usou, é como se tivesse especificado o `FILTER_DEFAULT`, que equivale ao `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`. Ou seja, no fim não filtra absolutamente nada, se não usar em conjunto com nenhuma *flag*.

Claro que o processo interno é um pouco diferente, mas isso não é relevante.

Um ponto importante é que muita gente pode começar achar que deve filtrar tudo, mas nem sempre é o adequado, precisa ter um motivo e saber o que está fazendo, porque não tem nada pior que a pessoa ter sensação de segurança sem estar seguro. Em muitos casos um filtro não é necessário, é só um dado descritivo, em outros precisa de um processamento específico manual e não tem algo pronto para lidar com isso. E tem os casos que essa validação e limpeza ocorrerá de outra forma, por exemplo com o [uso correto em uma *query*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101) em um banco de dados, onde grande parte dos *sites* sofrem, conforme a gente vê o pessoal postando aqui.

A melhor forma é a mais adequada para a situação e para saber isso precisa do caso específico e dominar todos os aspectos da programação. Mas a segunda, do jeito usado, claramente não tem vantagem alguma sobre a primeira.