# Como criar tabela em php?

Tags: php, mysql, unity3d

Estou fazendo uma aplicação na unity e nela necessito criar uma tabela via php. O código está semelhante a este:

```html
<?php
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = usuario;
  $pass = senha;
  $dbname = banco;
  $pdo;
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".$host, $user, $pass);
    //$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    //$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    print_r( $e );
  }
    $nomeDaTabela = $_GET['nomeDaTabela'];
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE :t ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;");
    $sql->bindValue(":t", $nomeDaTabela);
    $sql->execute();
    echo "Ready";
?>
```

Entretanto nada acontece, quero deixar claro que já testei se a Unity está passando o nome da tabela, e a resposta é sim. Mas por algum motivo o php não está interpretando. Também quero deixar claro que quando eu troco o ":t" por nomeDaCena e retiro o $_GET e o bindValue, cria a tabela normalmente.

Answer (score -4):

Provalmente você precisa concatenar a string.
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php
Segundo o manual do PDO o prepare precisa de uma STRING

public PDO::prepare(string $query, array $options = []): PDOStatement|false

$nomeDaTabela = $_GET['nomeDaTabela'];
$sql = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE :t ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;")

Tenta assim... Concatenação de string.
$sql = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE".$nomeDaTablea." ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;" )

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Leitura importante: [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/70)