# É suficiente escapar a saida, se não filtrar a entrada?

Tags: php

Quero saber se e seguro inserir os dados sem filtrar/higienizar a entrada do usuário se usar PDO e depois retornar com htmlspecialchars() como está sendo feito no código abaixo:

```
<?
include_once('conexao.php');

//Pre validação
$titulo = isset($_POST['titulo']) ? $_POST['titulo'] : null;

if(empty($titulo)){
    echo json_encode( ['error' => 'Titulo vazio']);
    die();
}

if(mb_strlen($titulo) > 155){
    echo json_encode( ['error' => 'Titulo muito grande']);
    die();
}

// Inserção de dados e captura id
$inserir = sql($db, "INSERT INTO ofertas(titulo) VALUES (?)", array($titulo), "lastid");

// Select e exibe
$exibir = sql($db, "SELECT * FROM ofertas WHERE id = ?", array($inserir), "rows");

echo htmlspecialchars($exibir['titulo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

A função sql()

```
<?
define("HOST", 'localhost');
define("USER", 'root');
define("PASS", 'fikTiciaHaTx89,ch@v');
define("NAME", 'meudb');

//Conectamos ao banco de dados
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".NAME.";charset=utf8mb4", "".USER."", "".PASS."");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Erro ao conectar no banco de dados");
}

// Função basica para gerenciamento PDO
function sql($db_atual, $q, $params, $return) {
    
    try {

        //prepara a querry
        $stmt = $db_atual->prepare($q);

        //executa a query
        $stmt->execute($params);
        
        // retorna no formato solicitado pela variavel
        if ($return == "rows") {
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }elseif ($return == "rowsall") {
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }elseif ($return == "count") {
            return $stmt->rowCount();
        }elseif( $return == "lastid"){
            return $db_atual->lastInsertId();
        }
        
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        
        echo "DataBase Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die();
        
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        
        echo "Erro Geral: ".$e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Tem muitos posts no site falando disso, e são vários aspectos diferentes, recomendo uma pesquisada. Mas seguem alguns links pra começar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/70 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/70 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/70 - mas tem vários outros aspectos além de SQL Injection, como quebra da aplicação, corrupção de dados no DB por incompatibilidade de campo (que não tem como saber depois que ocorreram, por exemplo um overflow que modifique o dado original ao inserir) e uma diversidade de situações que podem quebrar a aplicação.

Comment: ...e filtro de saída tem função completamente diferente dos filtros de entrada no contexto do post. Tem intersecção na parte de formatação, mas tem mais diferença do que similaridade. E parece também que está partindo das premissas erradas (até sobre "ter divergência" - não tem tanta divergência assim, o que tem é gente que publica coisas sem saber do que está falando, ai não é divergência, é erro mesmo). Lembrando que pode [edit] a pergunta e tratar de algum aspecto mais prático não coberto nas postagens já existentes, ai nesse caso a pergunta é revisada, tanto os pontos quanto o fechamento.